# Icons not showing up in bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native

Creating a bottom tab navigator and for some reason the Icons don't show up. The Icons show up when I use it outside of the bottom tab navigator. I looked through many stack overflow solutions and I implemented all of them but for some reason it still isn't working!

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
  Home: {
    screen: EventNavigator, 
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    tabBarIcon : ({tintColor}) => (
      <Ionicons name='ios-home' size={30} color={tintColor}/>
    )
  },
},
  Categories: {
    screen: CategoryNavigator,
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'Categories',
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Ionicons name='ios-search' size={30} color={tintColor} />
    )
  },
  },
  Favourite: {
    screen: FavouriteNavigator,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Favourite',
      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Ionicons name='ios-heart' size={30} color={tintColor}/>
      ),
    }
  },
},
{
  order: ['Home', 'Categories', 'Favourite'],
  tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    activeTintColor: "#00ACF0",
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
  }
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are putting them inside `defaultNavigationOptions` change it to `navigationOptions`. For example in Home:

```
Home: {
    screen: EventNavigator, 
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon : ({tintColor}) => (
            <Ionicons name='ios-home' size={30} color={tintColor}/>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ios-icons only visible in ios devices,if your using android device use this code run both devices successfully :)

`tabBarIcon:({navigation})=>(<Image source={require('...')} style={{...}}/>)`